# How do I test file uploading to remote server in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am implementing posting (uploading) a file to a remote server:

```
RestClient.post(server_url, :name_of_file_param => File.new('/myfile.txt','r'))
```

I'm curious about testing it: is it possible to test it somehow? Or maybe there is an online service that allows uploading a file by http?

Please note that `server_url` is a remote server and it's not **my** `Rails` application.

Comment: It depends what you want.  Do you want a functional test that assures that the POST is called with the params you want?  Or do you want to do a full integration test where you test if the file is completely uploaded.  Usually I think a functional test will suffice.

Comment: It doesn't matter actually. At least I would like one of them. Ideally - both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to do a functional test. To do this, you would typically mock the network connection. For ideas, take a look at the VCR gem for mocking HTTP connections and their results: https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr

A more detailed way is to write a round-trip test, where you upload the file, then download it, and compare the two to ensure they're identical. This is an integration test. It does not use mocks. Some APIs may provide proof-of-delivery, for example by returning a file checksum in the HTTP response; use these if you can.

If your data is high value, I do recommend the integration test, and doing some load testing and benchmarking as well. This is to be sure the data arrives safely and in the time you expect. When I did this for a real app, the integration testing did discover a problem with the remote server affecting approximately 1% of the files.